# use max() in the derived table returned unexpected result

Tags: mysql

Write an SQL query to find the customer_number for the customer who has placed the largest number of orders.

```
Input: 
Orders table:
+--------------+-----------------+
| order_number | customer_number |
+--------------+-----------------+
| 1            | 1               |
| 2            | 2               |
| 3            | 3               |
| 4            | 3               |
+--------------+-----------------+
Output: 
+-----------------+
| customer_number |
+-----------------+
| 3               |
+-----------------+
```

my SQL:

```
select max(c.d),customer_number from (Select Count(order_number) as d,customer_number  from Orders group by customer_number) as c
```

expected result:

```
[2,3]
```

actual result:

```
[2,1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `LIMIT` query here:

```sql
SELECT customer_number, COUNT(*) AS num_orders
FROM Orders
GROUP BY customer_number
ORDER BY num_orders DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Assuming you could have ties for two or more customers having the same maximum number of orders, then using `RANK` would be the easiest way on MySQL 8+:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT customer_number, COUNT(*) AS num_orders,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rnk
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY customer_number
)

SELECT customer_number, num_orders
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: thanks,but i also want to know why my SQL not working

Comment: Your invocation of the `MAX()` function in the outer query does not mean that you can just select the row having the max count.  You need to use one of the options in my answer to do that.

Comment: But why this query (SELECT ProductName,Min(Price) FROM [Products]) work in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_min but mine doesn't

Comment: ...in that query you are just asking for the lowest price.  If you wanted to _also_ select other columns, you would need something more complex.

Comment: I also query the product name and the result is correct, please try to use (SELECT ProductName,Min(Price) FROM [Products]). Therefore, I can't understand why my max() function is not working if these above examples work.

Comment: `select max(c.d),customer_number` makes no sense, because `MAX()` finds a single value from _all_ records in the table, whereas `customer_number` does not refer to one record, but rather all records.  You need some way to tell MySQL to find the entire _record_ having the max value.  See my answer for a few ways to do this.